# Steffensen's method. Consider the iteration formula $x_{n+1}=x_n-f(x_n)/g(x_n)$ where $g(x)=[f(x+f(x))-f(x)]/f(x)$. Show that this quadratically

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, numerical-methods

**Steffensen's method. Consider the iteration formula**

**$$x_{n+1}=x_n-f(x_n)/g(x_n)$$**

**where**

**$$g(x)=[f(x+f(x))-f(x)]/f(x)$$**

**Show that this quadratically convergent, under suitable hypotheses.**

I have to prove that there is a $C>0$ such that $|x_{n+1}-r|\leq C|x_n-r|^2$ where $r$ is the root I want to find, in other words I want $|e_{n+1}|\leq C|e_n|^2$, where $e_n=x_n-r$. I have tried to do the following $e_{n+1}=x_{n+1}-r=x_n-f(x_n)/g(x_n)-r=e_n-f(x_n)/g(x_n)$, but I do not know what else to follow. Could anyone help me, please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You start with $x_n=r+\epsilon$ where $f(r)=0$. Then
$$f(x_n)=f(r+\epsilon)=f(r)+\epsilon f^{\prime}(r)+\frac12\epsilon^2f^{\prime\prime}(r)+O(\epsilon^3)=\epsilon f^{\prime}(r)+\frac12\epsilon^2f^{\prime\prime}(r)+O(\epsilon^3)$$
And on to
$$\begin{align}f(x_n+f(x_n))&=f(r+\epsilon+f(r+\epsilon))=f\left(r+\epsilon(1+f^{\prime}(r))+\frac12\epsilon^2f^{\prime\prime}(r)+O(\epsilon^3)\right)\\
&=f(r)+\epsilon(1+f^{\prime}(r))f^{\prime}(r)+\frac12\epsilon^2f^{\prime\prime}(r)f^{\prime}(r)+\frac12\epsilon^2f^{\prime\prime}(r)(1+f^{\prime}(r))^2+O(\epsilon^3)\\
&=\epsilon(1+f^{\prime}(r))f^{\prime}(r)+\frac12\epsilon^2f^{\prime\prime}(r)(1+3f^{\prime}(r)+(f^{\prime}(r))^2)+O(\epsilon^3)\end{align}$$
**EDIT**: It seems the easier path at this point is to dispense with intermediate expressions and attack the final result directly:
$$\begin{align}x_{n+1}&=x_n-\frac{\left(f(x_n)^2\right)}{f\left(x_n+f(x_n)\right)-f(x_n)}\\
&=r+\epsilon\\
&\quad-\frac{\left(\epsilon f^{\prime}(r)+\frac12\epsilon^2f^{\prime\prime}(r)+O(\epsilon^3)\right)^2}{\epsilon\left(1+f^{\prime}(r)\right)f^{\prime}(r)+\frac12\epsilon^2\left(1+3f^{\prime}(r)+\left(f^{\prime}(r)\right)^2\right)f^{\prime\prime}(r)+O(\epsilon^3)-\epsilon f^{\prime}(r)-\frac12\epsilon^2f^{\prime\prime}(r)+O(\epsilon^3)}\\
&=r+\epsilon-\frac{\epsilon^2\left(f^{\prime}(r)\right)^2+\epsilon^3f^{\prime}(r)f^{\prime\prime}(r)+O(\epsilon^4)}{\epsilon\left(f^{\prime}(r)\right)^2+\frac12\epsilon^2\left(3f^{\prime}(r)+\left(f^{\prime}(r)\right)^2\right)f^{\prime\prime}(r)+O(\epsilon^3)}\\
&=r\\
&\quad+\frac{\epsilon^2\left(f^{\prime}(r)\right)^2+\frac12\epsilon^3\left(3f^{\prime}(r)+\left(f^{\prime}(r)\right)^2\right)f^{\prime\prime}(r)+O(\epsilon^4)-\epsilon^2\left(f^{\prime}(r)\right)^2-\epsilon^3f^{\prime}(r)f^{\prime\prime}(r)+O(\epsilon^4)}{\epsilon\left(f^{\prime}(r)\right)^2+\frac12\epsilon^2\left(3f^{\prime}(r)+\left(f^{\prime}(r)\right)^2\right)f^{\prime\prime}(r)+O(\epsilon^3)}\\
&=r+\frac{\frac12\epsilon^3\left(f^{\prime}(r)+\left(f^{\prime}(r)\right)^2\right)f^{\prime\prime}(r)+O(\epsilon^4)}{\epsilon\left(f^{\prime}(r)\right)^2+\frac12\epsilon^2\left(3f^{\prime}(r)+\left(f^{\prime}(r)\right)^2\right)f^{\prime\prime}(r)+O(\epsilon^3)}\\
&=r+\frac{\frac12\epsilon^3\left(f^{\prime}(r)+\left(f^{\prime}(r)\right)^2\right)f^{\prime\prime}(r)\left(1+O(\epsilon)\right)}{\epsilon\left(f^{\prime}(r)\right)^2\left(1+O(\epsilon)\right)}\\
&=r+\frac12\epsilon^2\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(r)}{f^{\prime}(r)}\left(1+f^{\prime}(r)\right)+O(\epsilon^3)\end{align}$$

So there you have it:
$$|x_{n+1}-r|=\frac12|x_n-r|^2\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(r)}{f^{\prime}(r)}(1+f^{\prime}(r))+O(|x_n-r|^3)$$
With assumptions like: $x_n$ is close enough to $r$ that a linear approximation is not too bad and also that $f(x)$ has a continuous second derivative in some neighborhood of $x=r$.

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Maybe when I compute $g(x_n)$ I shouldn't have divided through the denominator because I was going to take the reciprocal anyway. Then in the last phase I might have been better off adding $\epsilon$ before dividing by the denominator because then I could have represented it by $(f^{\prime}(r))^2+O(\epsilon^2)$, thus saving one extra term in the reciprocal. In fact it might have been easier to have directly computed $$r+\epsilon-\frac{(f(r+\epsilon))^2}{f(r+\epsilon+f(r+\epsilon))-f(r+\epsilon)}$$ in the first place. Almost certainly easier.

Comment: See edits. Hopefully a little simpler.